# How to assign specific colors to specific cell values in a raster file?

Tags: r, plot, rgb, raster, r-raster

I have a raster file with values ranging from 1 to 64, I want to assign specific colors to specific values, for example, I want that cells equal to 1 be painted as rgb 96,0,232, cells equal to 2 as 141,0,255, and so on.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Since this question is sticking around without much attention, can you be a little more detail to your question? It sounds like you want to associate a table with a raster value? So the table might look something like `1: 96,0,232 ; 2 : 141, 0, 255 ; ...`

Comment: Did you check this page?  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.5-8/topics/colortable

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something like below, see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.5-8/topics/colortable

```
# raster
r <- raster(matrix(sample(1:2, size=16, replace=T),nrow=4))
# color
col <- matrix(c(96,0,232, 141,0,255),ncol=3)
col <- apply(col,1, function(x) paste('#', paste( as.hexmode(x), collapse=''), sep='')
# colortable
colortable(r) <- col
```